# How do I convert (or cast) a String value to an Integer value?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, casting

Using Spark 2.1 (on Databricks), I have a table which has a column of type String as a result of an import from a .CSV file. In a SELECT query against that table, I am attempting to convert that column's value into an Integer before using the column value in a mathematical operation. I have been unable to find the right Spark SQL "function" to do this.

Below is an example of the SQL. "TO_NUMBER" isn't working on either of the two Strings; Sum_GN_POP or Count1:

```
SELECT name AS geohashPrefix3, TO_NUMBER(Sum_GN_POP) AS totalPopulation, TO_NUMBER(Count1) AS landMass
    FROM wayne_geohash3
   WHERE (LENGTH(name) = 3)
```

And it would be helpful if I could find the documentation for this. I will want to do other kinds of conversions (or casts) with other types, too. Any guidance on either or both of this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest do use an udf to do the parsing....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Summary:**
Apache [Spark's SQL](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/compatibility/hive.html) has partial compatibility with [Apache Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Home). So, most SQL that can be written in Hive can be written in Spark SQL.

**Detail:**
To convert a STRING to a specific numeric type like INT, a cast may be used. The cast consists of wrapping the target with parenthesis and preceding the parenthesis with the type to which it is to be changed. For example, the cast might look like this:

```
INT(someStringValue)
```

So, to make the SQL in the original posted question work, it needs to be changed to look like this (replacing the original function named "TO_NUMBER" with "INT"):

```
SELECT name AS geohashPrefix3, INT(Sum_GN_POP) AS totalPopulation, INT(Count1) AS landMass
  FROM wayne_geohash3
 WHERE (LENGTH(name) = 3)
```

Answer (score 17):

You can get it as `Integer` from the `csv` file using the option **inferSchema** like this :

```
val df = spark.read.option("inferSchema", true).csv("file-location")
```

That being said : the inferSchema option do make mistakes sometimes and put the type as `String`. if so you can use the `cast` operator on `Column`

**Dataframe/Dataset Implemetation :**

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("Count1", $"Count1" cast "Int" as "landMass").withColumn("Count1", $"Sum_GN_POP" cast "Int" as "totalPopulation")
```

**SQL Implemetation :**

```
SELECT name AS geohashPrefix3, CAST(Sum_GN_POP as INT) AS totalPopulation, CAST(Count1 AS INT) AS landMass
    FROM wayne_geohash3
   WHERE (LENGTH(name) = 3)
```

Comment: I'm not ready to do that yet. Your answer while correct is incomplete. My answer is what I was originally trying to find. I'm still unable to tell if my answer is really a cast or something else.

Answer (score 3):

I would to it using an UDF because Spark's cast will not capture variable overflow:

```
val parseInt = udf((s:String) => scala.util.Try{Some(s.toInt)}.getOrElse(None))

Seq("100", "10000000000", "1x0")
  .toDF("i")
  .select(
    $"i" cast "int" as "casted_result",
    parseInt($"i") as "udf_result"
  ).show

+-------------+----------+
|casted_result|udf_result|
+-------------+----------+
|          100|       100|
|   1410065408|      null|
|         null|      null|
+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: This is too much off the Spark SQL trail for a simple String to Int conversion on a throw away query where I already know the column value has been constrained. However, your answer is still valuable for when I do need that level of guarding.

Answer (score 3):

Haroun's answer about casting in Sql works for me. But **notice** that, if the number in the string is bigger than `integer`, result will be `null`. For numbers bigger than `integer` (`long` or `bigint`), the cast should be like:

```
CAST(Sum_GN_POP as BIGINT)
```